# How to share utils class across modules

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have a Jhipster gateway application and I would like to reuse a search modal form nested in two different parent forms.

I have put the **ateco-search.component.ts** shared class under **app/shared/model/subjects/utils**:

```
app
 |_shared
   |_model
     |_subjects
       |_utils
         |_ ateco-search.component.ts
 |_entities
   |_subjects
     |_ateco
     |_demand
```

It looks like:

```
import ...;

@Component({
    selector: 'ateco-search-component',
    template: `
        <div class="modal-header">
        ...
        </div>`
})
export class AtecoSearchComponent {...}
```

And I would like to call it under ateco module. In **ateco-update.component.ts** I have:

```
import {AtecoSearchComponent} from "app/shared";

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-ateco-update',
    templateUrl: './ateco-update.component.html'
})
export class AtecoUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    openSearchAtecoModal() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AtecoSearchComponent, {size: 'lg', ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'});
        ...
```

And likewise under demand module in **demand-update.component.ts**, I have:

```
import {AtecoSearchComponent} from "app/shared";

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-demand-update',
    templateUrl: './demand-update.component.html'
})
export class DemandUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    openSearchAtecoModal() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AtecoSearchComponent, {size: 'lg', ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'});
```

But when I run the application, I cannot enter nor ateco-update page nor demand-update page, getting:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'.
```

How should I share the **ateco-search.component.ts** util class cross modules?

Comment: Services is the way to go.

Comment: is ateco-search.comonent.ts dependent of other modules in your tree?

Comment: Well, it imports some jhpster/angular modules and from the app: 
import {Ateco} from 'app/shared/model/subjects/ateco.model';
import {AtecoService} from 'app/entities/subjects/ateco/ateco.service';
import {ATECO_ITEMS_PER_PAGE} from 'app/shared';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Utils Module for sharing the component:

**utils.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AtecoSearchComponent } from './ateco-search/ateco-search.component';
import { GatewaySharedModule } from 'app/shared';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AtecoSearchComponent],
    imports: [GatewaySharedModule, CommonModule],
    entryComponents: [AtecoSearchComponent],
    exports: [AtecoSearchComponent]
})
export class UtilsModule {}
```

Import it in the modules of the component where you want to use it (Eg. **demand.module.ts**)

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [GatewaySharedModule, RouterModule.forChild(ENTITY_STATES), UtilsModule],
     ...
})
```

Use the shared component:

```js
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AtecoSearchComponent, { size: 'lg', ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' });
})
```